# php filter_var and FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED

Tags: php, filter-var

How do I tell PHP 7.1.3 that when I use filter_var to validate a URL, that the scheme is NOT required?  just saying www.google.com for example is a completely valid URL, but filter_var will return false for that.  I see that I can add flags, but not how to remove them.

```
<?php

$url = 'www.google.com';

$sanitized = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$valid = filter_var($sanitized, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
if ($valid) {
  echo "Yes\n";
} else {
  echo "'$sanitized' is not valid\n";
}
```

Comment: A code example for people to see is always useful

Comment: Code example added.